# Delete row PHP JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to eliminate rows clicking on the button of each row. The JavaScript don't work right now. I can't find the problem. Any help? This part doesn't work Ajax, PHP scripts works well.

```js
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
                    <script>
                        
                       function eliminar() {
                           
                           var idpedido = $(this).attr('id');
                           
                           $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: 'eliminar pedido.php',
                        data: idpedido: idpedido,
                        success: function (data) { 
                        location.reload();
            }
                        });
                        }
          </script>
```

```html
<table borde='2'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Idpedido</th>
    <th>Pedido</th>
    <th>Estado</th>
    <th>Idempleado</th>
    <th>Idcocinero</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    // Bucle while que recorre cada registro y muestra cada campo en la tabla.
    while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ))  
    { ?>
         <tr name=pedidos id="<?php echo $columna ['idpedido']; ?>">
           <td><?php echo $columna ['idpedido']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $columna ['pedido']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $columna ['estado']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $columna ['idempleado']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $columna ['idcocinero']; ?></td>
           <td><button name="eliminar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-xl-4 py-xl-3" onclick="eliminar();" value="<?php echo $columna ['idpedido']; ?>"><span></span> Eliminar Pedido</button></td>
    <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: So start reducing your problem: does the POST call run? (open your dev tools, look at the network tab, and see what happens). If the call itself works, with the URL being the right one: JS has nothing to do with the problem and you can completely ignore it and focus on what PHP does on that POST call. You won't even need a browser to test the PHP side (just use `curl` on the command line instead for much faster testing).

Comment: What does `eliminar pedido.php` do?  (Also, URLs really shouldn't have spaces like that.)  What is the purpose of reloading the page after an AJAX operation?  Why do you expect a row to be removed?  Where in any of this code do you "delete a row" at all?  When you debug, are there any errors at all on the browser's development console?  Does the JavaScript function get invoked?  Does the AJAX operation get invoked?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?  There's a lot of debugging you can do here...

Comment: I do a query and create the table with the information, then I want to clicking in the delete button do a AJAX post and send the id to the PHP script to delete from the DB.

Comment: please note, your BUTTON doesn't have an ID. This (which is super horrible) will call your eliminar function passing the ID: `onclick="eliminar( <?php echo columna['idpedido'];  ?> );"`

Comment: or, change the attribute `value="..."` to `id="..."`

Answer (score 0):

I will not add any PHP to your code as you seem to be able to populate the table without issue.

I would add a class to the row, it does not have to be an ID as you can use the `e.target`, event target to ***target*** the ***closest*** ***row*** traversing up the DOM to get the ***row*** your button and content are in.

Query the selector using `document.querySelectorAll('button[name="eliminar"')` then remove it using an ***eventHandler***, nested inside a loop, no unique ids are needed in this case as the button is identified by the event in the event handler. `removeBtn.forEach(row => {` to iterate through the ***nodeList*** of potential *table row buttons*, then target the events button using, `row.addEventListener('click', removeRow)`. `removeRow` will be your call back passing the event into it as a parameter.

***NOTE:*** This will ONLY affect the displaying of information in the front end, if you wish to remove info from your database, you will also need to run a query to your database and remove info there using PHP.

```js
const removeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('button[name="eliminar"')

function removeRow(e) {
  // you may want to add logic that confirms removal before actual removal...

  // use the event.target and get the closest element with class of 'row'
  //.remove() removes the element from the DOM
  e.target.closest('.row').remove()
}

removeBtn.forEach(row => {
  row.addEventListener('click', removeRow)
})
```

```html
<table borde='2'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Idpedido</th>
      <th>Pedido</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
      <th>Idempleado</th>
      <th>Idcocinero</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
    // Bucle while que recorre cada registro y muestra cada campo en la tabla.
    while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ))  
    { ?>
      <tr class="row" name=pedidos id="<?php echo $columna ['idpedido']; ?>">
        <td>
          <?php echo $columna ['idpedido']; ?>test</td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $columna ['pedido']; ?>test</td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $columna ['estado']; ?>test</td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $columna ['idempleado']; ?>test</td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $columna ['idcocinero']; ?>test</td>
        <td><button name="eliminar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-xl-4 py-xl-3" value="<?php echo $columna ['idpedido']; ?>">Eliminar Pedido</button></td>
        <?php } ?>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```